# Jquery Scrolling Tilt

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Why is the if statement not working? The code is set to rotate a certain object by sdegree.
The older code used to work without the if statement so im assuming the problem is there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
  var sdegree = 0;
  var orig = 0; 
  $(window).scroll(function() {
        if (sdegree > -30 && sdegree < 30 && sdegree-orig>=0) {
            sdegree + 4;
            orig = sdegree,
        } else if (sdegree > -30 && sdegree < 30 && sdegree-orig<0 ) {
            sdegree + 4;
            orig = sdegree,
        } else if (sdegree < -30) {
            sdegree + 4;
            orig = sdegree,
        } else if (sdegree > 30) {
            sdegree - 4;
            orig = sdegree;
        } else {
            orig = sdegree;
        }
    var srotate = "rotate(" + sdegree + "deg)";
    $(".plane").css({
      transform : srotate
    });
  });
});   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably meant:

```
sdegree += 4;
```

or

```
sdegree = sdegree + 4;
```

Notice the equals sign here.  Otherwise you are doing nothing and `sdegree` is always 0.

**Edit:** I also just noticed you have commas at the ends of some of your lines in place of semicolons.  Always check your browser console for js errors.

```
orig = sdegree,
```

should be:

```
orig = sdegree;
```

Comment: The two code snippets above are equivalent.  I added the 2nd in case you were unfamiliar with `+=`.

Comment: it still isn't working. is it something other than the if statement?

Comment: Well you'll have to be more specific than that.  With those changes it does "work", it just may not do what you expect.  But from your question there is no way to know what it is you are expecting.  http://jsfiddle.net/NjkZr/2/  The syntax errors are fixed and it does "something" without error.